# How do i run async Promises without promise hell?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want get files in directory, open them, process them, and write result.
I want do all step async with Promises

First thing came to my head was

```
read_dir('/tmp')
  .then(function(files){
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
      read_file(files[i])
        .then(function(file_data){
          var processed_data = process_work_convert(file_data.data);
          return {'filename': file_data.name, 'data': processed_data}
        })
        .then(function(file_data){
          return write_file(file_data.filename, file_data.data);
        })
        .then(function(){
          console.log('success');
        })
    }
  })
```

But it looks like standard callback way (callback hell)

I can use `Promise.all` but it will make my code synchronous

I want some magic `then_each` and `catch_each`

example:

```
read_dir('/tmp')
  .then_each(function(file){
    return read_file(file);
  })
  .then_each(function(file_data){
    var processed_data = process_work_convert(file_data.data);
    return {'filename': file_data.name, 'data': processed_data}
  })
  .then_each(function(file_data){
    return write_file(file_data.filename, file_data.data);
  })
  .then_each(function(){
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch_each(function(){
    console.log('error');
  });
```

Does this function exist ?

Or may be you know how extend Promise to achive this?

Or may be there is some othe way to do this?

Comment: Is your goal to produce a folder explorer ? Have you considered  using a recursive method ? For more doc on Promises, you can also look at Mozilla doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: no, not a folder explorer. I want get all log files from folder and convert it to other format.

Comment: "*I can use Promise.all but it will make my code synchronous*" - wait what? No.

Comment: it is not very important folder explorer or something else. I can get list of urls with first request and then process each url. i want do it async and beautifull. And i want some Promise practice. But it makes no sense if i get same result as if i were using callbacks

Comment: "*But it looks like standard callback way (callback hell)*" - nope. Callback hell is when you need to nest callbacks for every asynchronous step you do - and *chaining* `then` calls is exactly not that.

Comment: It looks like `process_work_convert` is actually synchronous. There's no reason to put `write_file` in the next `then` callback then.

Comment: Promise.all waits for all promises to finish. But i want process files right it was read. If i have to small files and one very big, i do not want to wait for big file being read

Comment: even if `process_work_convert` is sync, small file can be read, processed, and written, while big file still in read process

Comment: @CyberLis You wouldn't use `Promise.all` after every step, you'd use it after the last step only so that you get the `success` log only once when everything is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking for is

```
read_dir('/tmp')
.then(function(files){
    return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
        return read_file(file)
        .then(function(file_data) {
            return write_file(file_data.name, process_work_convert(file_data.data));
        });
    }));
})
.then(function(){
    console.log('success');
}, function(e){
    console.log('error', e);
});
```

There is no callback hell here, just some extra indentation from the looping.

If you want to do with less callbacks, have a look at the upcoming [`async`/`await` syntax](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait):

```
(async function() {
    var files = await read_dir('/tmp');
    await Promise.all(files.map(async function(file) {
        var file_data = await read_file(file);
        await write_file(file_data.name, process_work_convert(file_data.data));
    }));
    console.log('success');
}())
.catch(function(e){
    console.log('error', e);
});
```

> Does this function exist?

No, it cannot (at least without the synchronisation that you are trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

You may find [relign](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign) to be helpful here. Here's your code example written with relign [parallelMap](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign#parallel-map) and ES6 arrow functions.

```
read_dir('/tmp')
  .then(fileNames => relign.parallelMap(fileNames, fileName =>
    read_file(fileName)
      .then(file => ({ filename: file.name, data: process_work_convert(file.data) }))
      .then(data => write_file(data.filename, data.data))))
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```